# Special char accentuation '~' on Ã or Õ not showing on table in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have this code https://jsfiddle.net/nbadnkb8/10/ and it can't show Ã or Õ on the table cells when i click the '~' keyword in Safari (IOS), but in Chrome works fine (both systems ios and windows). Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
var inp = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
if ((!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(inp) || e.keyCode == 96)) && e.keyCode != 8){
  reCalculate(e);
  rePosition();
  // if key is an arrow key, don't type the user input.
  // if it is any other key (a, b, c, etc)
  // edit the text
  if (e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the header on your page.